# Why can't I run the JS that is in the database?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, nashorn

I need to run a JS command that is saved in string format in mongoDB. Why do not run to the data in uppercase?

Java

```
public String read(String chave, String valor){
        String processador = atributoDAO.getProcessador(chave);
        if(processador != null){
            ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
            try {
                engine.eval(processador);
                Invocable invocable = (Invocable)engine;
                valor = (String)invocable.invokeFunction("process", valor);
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                Log.error(AtributoReader.class, "erro no engine js", e);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                Log.error(AtributoReader.class, "erro no engine js", e);
            }
            return valor;
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

Database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55390277e230ebff4fe25755"),
    "atributo" : "peca_nome",
    "processador" : "function(val) { return val.toUpperCase(); }"
}
```

Comment: Have you printed out the javascript to make sure that it isn't escaping it somewhere?

Comment: What happens when you run the code and what do you want it to happen instead?

Comment: I have a `NoSuchMethodException` in `valor = (String)invocable.invokeFunction("process", valor);`

Comment: I tried insert in database: `function process(val) { return val.toUpperCase(); }` but keeps not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eval an anonymous function and store the result as an object. The resulting object is of type ScriptObjectMirror (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html) which has a method to call (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html#call-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) that function.

The code goes like

```
Object thiz = engine.eval("this"); // get you global object
ScriptObjectMirror func = engine.eval("function() { print('hello'); }");
func.call(thiz); // pass global object as "this" for the function
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute `engine.eval("function(val) { return val.toUpperCase(); }")` you create an anonymous function in the scope of your scripting engine. Unfortunately there is no way to call it later, because the function is not assigned to a variable.

Your call `invocable.invokeFunction("process", valor);` tries to call a `function process( val )`, but no function with that name exists in the context of your script engine. So it throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.

There are two possible solutions for this.

Either rewrite the code snippets in your database to assign the function to a variable so you can call it later:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55390277e230ebff4fe25755"),
    "atributo" : "peca_nome",
    "processador" : "process = function(val) { return val.toUpperCase(); };"
}
```

Or alternatively, use Java to add the variable to the Javascript sourcecode before you compile the script:

```
engine.eval("process = " + processador);
```

**By the way:** Storing executable code in the database is often a very risky idea security-wise. When there is any way to get user-provided data into those code snippets, you open up your application to a dangerous code execution vulnerability. By default the nashorn script engine is not sandboxed at all and extremely powerful. It can do anything the JavaVM can do, including calling any method or construct any object from your project and from the java standard library. What you are doing here looks as if you are going to juggle with loaded guns. *If* you know what you are doing and *if* you follow all security precautions it *might* be safe, but it looks like you are just about to shoot yourself (or someone else).

Comment: Doesn't works =( But works with `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55391f7681359593d7993844"),
    "atributo" : "peca_nome",
    "processador" : "function process(val){return val.toUpperCase();}"
}` idk why.

Comment: /By default the nashorn script engine is not sandboxed at all and extremely powerful. It can do anything the JavaVM can do, including calling any method or construct any object.../ That is not entirely accurate. If your java code is run with security manager is turned on, any evaluated JS code is run with null CodeSource => code is run as untrusted, sandboxed code and so gets no special permissions (like an untrusted applet code).